# Is decrypting BitLocker after deleting files a secure way to erase data?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, bitlocker, secure-erase

Consider the task of erasing profiles of previous users from a Windows computer (which is to be given away to other people) without having to fully erase the system.

Assuming the computer's hard drive (with NTFS) was previously fully-encrypted with BitLocker, is the following procedure a valid approach?

- Delete the users along with their home directories.
- Remove Bitlocker, decrypting the drive in the process.

The logic is that the decryption process should only affect the existing files, hence the deleted ones would remain effectively garbled with an unrecoverable key of the previous BitLocker setup.

Is this true or does BitLocker do things differently (e.g. it somehow decrypts data of deleted files as well). Would the profile directories be still recoverable after that somehow (and if so, how exactly?)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't really decrypt BitLocker. You turn it off, and the disk becomes readable by anything, but the data doesn't change. Only encrypting it again with a different password would change the data. Erased data is always unaffected anyway, unless you encrypt the entire disk, but then secure erase is a far better option still.

Comment: This sounds strange. Firstly, how can the data be left unchanged if previously the disk was unreadable without a password and now it is. Secondly, what was BitLocker doing while showing the "Decrypting data..." progress bar then?

Comment: @KT. - It was moving/copying the original encrypted data from one location and writing decrypted data to a new location, and getting rid of the original data.

Comment: This means that it was, after all, literally decrypting data. But if it was decrypting everything, including the currently unused sectors, I get the point (but I find the formulation somewhat unclear).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Assuming the computer's hard drive (with NTFS) was previously
>   fully-encrypted with BitLocker, is the following procedure a valid
>   approach?
>
> - Delete the users along with their home directories.
> - Remove Bitlocker, decrypting the drive in the process.

When you encrypt a drive with BitLocker, each byte is basically copied and the copy is encrypted, while during the decryption process the opposite is true.  If you delete the drive, then decrypt an empty partition, it's possible you will run into firmware optimization issues which ignore writing all 0's to a drive.  This wouldn't necessarily be a bad thing since you would be keeping random data.  However, it certainly isn't what you are attempting to do, by doing what you describe.

A better method would be to delete your personal files, then delete the partition, this makes data recovery virtually impossible.  Even if somebody was able to recover the entire partition, they wouldn't be able to decrypt the data without the key, required to decrypt the data.  Instead of removing the partition, Windows 10 Fresh Start, will result in a clean Windows 10 installation.

> The logic is that the decryption process should only affect the existing files, hence the deleted ones would remain effectively garbled with an unrecoverable key of the previous BitLocker setup.

The BitLocker decryption process affects all data on the drive.  So your logic has a major fallacy, in that BitLocker does not actually work, the way you think it does.

> Is this true or does BitLocker do things differently (e.g. it somehow decrypts data of deleted files as well). Would the profile directories be still recoverable after that somehow (and if so, how exactly?)

BitLocker does not do things differently, then any other full disk encryption solution, VeraCrypt (aka TrueCrypt) works in a very similar way.

> Would the profile directories be still recoverable after that somehow
>   (and if so, how exactly?

How your profile data could be recovered is beyond my skill to describe, but based on your description of what you want to do, and my knowledge of BitLocker it isn't a guaranteed method of making it impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no, instead of the way bitlocker will decrypt your data the files still are there, and formatting a single time could be not enough to prevent to find out data with a recover software.

To erase low level a disk completely you can use:

- https://dban.org/

Instead for erase files in a disk you do not want to erase completely search for a file shredder software, I know this one:

- http://www.fileshredder.org/